# Run Multiple AWS EC2 Instances Simultaneously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wish to launch multiple `Amazon Web Service EC2` instances simultaneously.  For example, I hope to run 1000 models on one instance and a separate 1000 models on a second instance.

When I click `Request Spot Instances` I select `2 instances` under the `Total target capacity` option.  Then I click the box to the left of `Maintain target capacity`.

A `fleet` is created consisting of: `m5d.12xlarge, r3.8xlarge, m5dn.8xlarge, m5n.8xlarge, r5n.8xlarge`.  This `fleet` is listed on the `Spot Requests` page.  `Capacity` for that `fleet` says `1 of 2`.  `Status` says `pending_fulfillment`.

However, only one `instance` is listed on the `Instances` page.  This `instance` is `running`.

Presumably I can only run the first set of 1000 models on this `instance`.  How can I initiate the second `instance` so I can run both sets of 1000 models simultaneously?

Must I simply wait until the `Capacity` column for the `fleet` on the `Spot Requests` page says `2 of 2`?  If so, how long does this take?  I tried waiting 25 minutes before creating this post.

**EDIT**

I found the following `error` message when clicking on `pending_fullfillment`:

```
1/13/2020, 3:03:39 PM   error   spotInstanceCountLimitExceeded
```

I had no idea there is a `Spot Instance` count limit.  Why would the option exist to select multiple `instances` if there is a limit of only one `instance`?

Comment: This question should not be closed.  It is perfectly appropriate for this forum.  If you feel otherwise, please explain why.

Answer (score 1):

Is your AWS account new? There's a standard limit of 20 spot instances, but new accounts have lower limits.

It's also possible that you've hit your limit for EC2 instances - go into the EC2 console and near the top left click "limits". If you can start an EC2 on-demand instance of the same type the spot won't create, then it's the spot limit rather than the EC2 limit.

You can [request a limit increase from AWS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/home#/case/create?issueType=service-limit-increase&limitType=service-code-ec2-fleet) (log in before you visit this link).